# Constructed nested Tuple2 in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I`m trying to have nested Tuple2, in order to save for each Vertex on my graph three values: id, weight and label.

Currently I have:

```
List<Tuple2<Object,Integer>> vertices = Lists.newArrayList(
         new Tuple2<Object,Integer>(1l,0),
         new Tuple2<Object,Integer>(2l,Integer.MAX_VALUE),
         new Tuple2<Object,Integer>(3l,Integer.MAX_VALUE),
         new Tuple2<Object,Integer>(4l,Integer.MAX_VALUE),
 );
```

And I`m trying to construct the nested Tuple2 like below:

```
List<Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>> vertices = Lists.newArrayList(
         new Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>(1l,(0,"A")),
         new Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>(2l,(Integer.MAX_VALUE,"B")),
         new Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>(3l,(Integer.MAX_VALUE,"C")),
         new Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>(4l,(Integer.MAX_VALUE,"D"))
);
```

but this gives me error.

Can you please help me, identifying what is wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because you didn't initialize internal tuples:

```
List<Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>> vertices = Lists.newArrayList(
     new Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>(
       1l, new Tuple2<Integer,String>(0,"A")
     ),
     new Tuple2<Object,Tuple2<Integer,String>>(
       2l, new (Integer.MAX_VALUE,"B")
     )
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user9717204